# Microsoft Visual C++ Run - time Check Failure #2

Tags: c

I don't understand why I keep getting this error. The program works fine, but it keeps giving me this error.

I think it might be something to do with the arrays, but I'm not 100% sure.

Any help that anyone can give me will be helpful to me. I'm not even a programmer. I'm just studying information technology, so I'm not super good at this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoH0x.png

```
int main(void)
{
// Constant and Variable Declarations
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 4;//decarling the array size
int homeScore[ARRAY_SIZE];
int awayScore[ARRAY_SIZE];
int finalHome = 0;
int finalAway = 0;


// *** Your program goes here ***
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    printf("How Many Points were Scored by Home Team in Quarter #%d? ", i);//getting the hometeam numbers
    scanf("%d", &homeScore[i]);
    while (homeScore[i] < 0) {  //checking continuously home team score negative or not
        printf("\tThe number entered cannot be negative. Please re-enter the number #%d? ", i);
        scanf("%d", &homeScore[i]);
    }

    printf("How Many Points were Scored by Away Team in Quarter #%d? ", i);//getting the awayteam numbers
    scanf("%d", &awayScore[i]);
    while (awayScore[i] < 0) {//checking continuously away team score negative or not
        printf("\tThe number entered cannot be negative. Please re-enter the number #%d? ", i);
        scanf("%d", &awayScore[i]);
    }printf("\n");
}

printf("After each quarter, the score was:");
//printing Score Board
printf("\n         H\t A\n");
printf("\t---\t---");
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    finalHome = finalHome + homeScore[i];//processing 
    finalAway = finalAway + awayScore[i];//processing
    printf("\nQ%d", i);
    printf("\t %d\t", finalHome);//printing out the scores for the home team
    printf(" %d\t", finalAway);//printing out scores for the away team
}
printf("\n");
if (finalHome > finalAway) {//printing out the home team win
    printf("Yea! The Home Team Won!\n");
}

else if (finalHome == finalAway) {//printing out if they tied
    printf("After 4 quarters, the score was tied.\n");
}

else {//printing out if the away team won
    printf("Sorry, the Away Team won.\n");
}
printf("\n");

return 0;
} // end main()
```

Comment: indexes for arrays in C go from 0 to len -1. Not from 1 to len as you have it

Comment: please dont post links to graphics. In the popup dialog you can go ctrl-C and windows will copy the text to the clipboard for you, you can then paste it here

Comment: @pm100 i tired not to but my rep isnt high enough to let me show the picture

Comment: just paste the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comment , C array indexes go from 0 to len -1 . So change

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i <4; i++) {
```

BTW it should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4;i++)
```

Not `for (int i = 0; i<= 4; i++)`
In array, we count from 0
Ex: array[0], array[1], array[n]

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I try to put the '\n' at the end of lines.  Here is your code with a few changes.

As was indicated by others, in c++, we generally run for loops from i = 0 to i < limit, since the arrays are indexed from 0.

```c++
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
// Constant and Variable Declarations
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 4;//decarling the array size
    int homeScore[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int awayScore[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int finalHome = 0;
    int finalAway = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("How Many Points were Scored by Home Team in Quarter #%d? ", i);//getting the hometeam numbers
        scanf("%d", &homeScore[i]);
        while (homeScore[i] < 0) {  //checking continuously home team score negative or not
            printf("\tThe number entered cannot be negative. Please re-enter the number #%d? ", i);
            scanf("%d", &homeScore[i]);
        }

        printf("How Many Points were Scored by Away Team in Quarter #%d? ", i);//getting the awayteam numbers
        scanf("%d", &awayScore[i]);
        while (awayScore[i] < 0) {//checking continuously away team score negative or not
            printf("\tThe number entered cannot be negative. Please re-enter the number #%d? ", i);
            scanf("%d", &awayScore[i]);
        }printf("\n");
    }

    printf("After each quarter, the score was:");
//printing Score Board
    printf("\n\t\tH\t  A\n");
    printf("\t\t---\t ---\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        finalHome = finalHome + homeScore[i];//processing
        finalAway = finalAway + awayScore[i];//processing
        printf("Q%d", i);
        printf("\t %3d", finalHome);//printing out the scores for the home team
        printf("\t %3d\n", finalAway);//printing out scores for the away team
    }
    if (finalHome > finalAway) {//printing out the home team win
        printf("Yea! The Home Team Won!\n");
    }

    else if (finalHome == finalAway) {//printing out if they tied
        printf("After 4 quarters, the score was tied.\n");
    }

    else {//printing out if the away team won
        printf("Sorry, the Away Team won.\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
} // end main()
```

Comment: this is not c++